# Table inheritance in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, uml, laravel-5.1

As a newbie to laravel, I have a problem with setting up my Laravel models correctly.
In my UML Diagram, I'm using [Generalization](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html) so that I can "inherit" some attributes from the parent table:
[image]

In my database, I have the following.

Entity table

```
-------------------
| id | identifier |
-------------------
| 1  |  AZX-C56   |
-------------------
| 2  |  AZX-C06   |
-------------------
| 3  |  MZX-9F1   |
-------------------
| 4  |  MZX-X09   |
-------------------
```

Worker table

```
---------------------------------------------
| id  | entity_id | firstname | lastname |..|
---------------------------------------------
|  1  |     1     |   Jean    |  Michel  |..|
---------------------------------------------
|  2  |     2     |   Jane    |    Doe   |..|
---------------------------------------------
```

Machine table

```
----------------------------------------------
| id  | entity_id |    Type   | Description  |
----------------------------------------------
|  1  |     3     |  XU-09-A  |  lorem ipsum |
----------------------------------------------
|  2  |     4     |  XZ-24-U  |  lorem ipsum |
----------------------------------------------
```

My models respectively:

```php
class Entity extends Model {
     protected $fillable = ['identifier'];

     public function worker(){
         return $this->hasOne(Worker::class);
     }
     public function machine(){
         return $this->hasOne(Machine::class);
     }
}
class Worker extends Model {
     protected $fillable = ['entity_id','firstname','lastname'];

     public function entity(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Entity::class);
     }

}
class Machine extends Model {
     protected $fillable = ['entity_id','type','description'];

     public function entity(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Entity::class);
     }

}
```

My question is: Am I doing it right, or is there a better way to map my tables correctly in Laravel ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an inheritance. It is an association. You are referencing the ids from the `Entity` table.

[image]

From what I see the id is used for either `Worker` or `Robot` so you should add the constraint with the `xor`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable addition. I will correct my model accordingly :)